# PHP login and set cookie properly

Tags: javascript, php, html, session, cookies

I have never worked with $_COOKIES, and now I've been given the task to make it work.

I have been following a couple of tutorials online.

Found here: http://www.phpnerds.com/article/using-cookies-in-php/2

And then here:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dsem42810H4

Neither of which worked for me.

Here is how my code ended up.  I shortened it as much as I could.

Starting with the index.php page, which contains the initial login form:

```
<form role="form" action="index.php" method="post" id="loginForm" name="loginForm">

  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" 
    value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])) echo $_COOKIE['username']; ?>" />

  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" 
   value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['password'])) echo $_COOKIE['password']; ?>"/>

  <button type="button" id="loginSubmit" name="loginSubmit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>

  <input type="checkbox" id="rememberme" 
    <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])){echo "checked='checked'";} ?> value="1" />

</form>
```

Here is the JavaScript used to send the form values:

```
$('#loginSubmit').on('click', function()
{
  var username = $('#username').val();
  var password = $('#password').val();
  var rememberme = $('#rememberme').val();

  // skipping the form validation

  $.post('api/checkLogin.php', {username: username, password: password, rememberme:rememberme}, function(data)
  {
    // the data returned from the processing script 
    // determines which page the user is sent to
    if(data == '0')
    {
      console.log('Username/Password does not match any records.');
    }
    if(data == 'reg-user")
    {
      window.location.href = "Home.php";
    }
    else
    {
      window.location.href = "adminHome.php";
    }
  });
});
```

Here is the processing script, called checkLogin.php.  This is where I attempt to set the $_COOKIE:

```
<?php
  include ("../include/sessions.php");

  if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
  {
    $username = strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['username'])));
    $password = strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['password'])));
    $rememberme = $_POST['rememberme'];

    $select = "SELECT username, fullname, password FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'";
    $query = mysqli_query($dbc, $select);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

    $dbusername = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['username']));
    $dbfullname = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['fullname']));
    $dbpassword = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['password']));

    if(password_verify($password, $dbpassword))
    {
      // setting sessions here
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
      $_SESSION['fullname'] = $dbfullname;

      // here is where I attempt to set the $_COOKIE
      if(isset($remember))
      {
        setcookie('username', $_POST['username'], time()+60*60*24*365);
        setcookie('password', $_POST['password'], time()+60*60*24*365);
      }
      else
      {
        setcookie('username', $_POST['username'], false);
        setcookie('password', $_POST['password'], false);
      }
      echo $username;  // this gets sent back to the JavaScript
      mysqli_free_result($query);   
    }
    else
    {
      // username/password does not match any records
      $out = 0;
      echo $out;
    }
  }
?>
```

So now that I have attempted to set the $_COOKIE, I can try to print it to the home page, like so:

```
<?php echo 'cookie ' . $_COOKIE["username"]; ?>
```

To which does not work, because all I see is the word 'cookie'.

Besides that, when I log out, I am hoping to see the login form already filled out, which is the overall task I have been trying to complete, but have been unsuccessful at doing so.

Comment: Storing sensitive information in cookies is not a good idea.

Comment: Sensitive information, such as the password.  Correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Understood.  How about only setting the cookie for the username?

Comment: well, your form is using a GET method, yet you're passing POST arrays; that should have triggered an undefined index here.

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: you shouldn't `escape()` string passwords.

Comment: I will definitely take your suggestions regarding the form and values, but I really would like to get the cookies to work.  I would appreciate any input you can provide regarding cookies.  Thank you.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - Any thoughts regarding the cookies?

Comment: `if(data == 'reg-user")` that has mixed quotes in the JS and should either be both singles or double quotes. Fix that, then use php's error reporting and run a `var_dump()` on variable/cookies etc. Far as I can tell, the rest looks ok to me.  If this is more of a JS related issue, I'm not the guy for this. JS and me don't make good bedfellows lol!

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - Thanks for your help.  I do appreciate it.

Comment: you're welcome.